# Showing/Hiding alarm clock icon programmatically in android

Tags: android

Tell me please, how can I achieve this? I know this is possible because some applications in android market can do this.

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. What do you mean by "show/hide the alarm clock"?. Which applications do this?

Comment: "Sleep as Android" does this. When you set up an alarm clock using standard app or "Sleep as Android" for example, alarm clock icon appears at the right corner of the status bar and disappears when you cancel the alarm clock. I want to know how can I "appear" and "disappear" that icon from my code.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution, it takes only 3 lines of code, here is it:

```
    Intent alarmChanged = new Intent("android.intent.action.ALARM_CHANGED");
    alarmChanged.putExtra("alarmSet", enabled);
    context.sendBroadcast(alarmChanged);
```

Comment: but how to hide that?